# MixerHostAudio Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, bluetooth, audiounit

I'm using MixerHostAudio to listen to what I'm saying, at the same moment I'm talking.
Than I can even use it with my Apple TV and it works.
My question is, can I speak and at the same moment hear what I'm saying on a bluetooth device ? Seems not cause I can't select my Bluetooth device while my app is opened.
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah this is a nice question.Even I am also trying for that.While we are speaking at one end(microphone) that should be played at same time at another end(Bluetooth speaker).

Answer (score 1):

Good Question.  I had a similar one and spent hours on the phone with Apple trying to get it answered.  Unfortunately iOS 7 does not allow AVAudioSession to have input and output configured independently.  The closest you can get is using the MultiRoute Category, but it does not currently support Bluetooth devices. Submit a bug report to Apple and hopefully they will add it to future versions of iOS.